# How to delete an empty team from a Bitbucket account?

Tags: bitbucket

I'm trying to clean up my BitBucket.org account and I am the remaining member of a team that never had any activity.

> [image: team overview]

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to delete this team or leave the team. It appears that the only path to resolve this is as follow:

1. Hover over "Manage members" and click on "Leave team".

   > [image: manage members]
2. Click on "Revoke my membership".

   > [image: revoke membership]

But that gives me an error:

> [image: error]

How can I delete this team or remove myself from it?

Comment: Oh. I just noticed that Bitbucket has their own [answers site](https://answers.atlassian.com/tags/bitbucket/) powered by [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/). I will cross post this there and share the answer if this gets resolved!

Answer (score 3):

If you are the last, remaining user in a team and you want to leave the team, you will need to delete the team:

1. At the top-right of the BitBucket website, click on your avatar and then click on "Manage account".

   [image: manage account]
2. Click on the "Account" dropdown menu and click on the team.

   [image: select account]
3. Click on "Delete account" menu item on the left.

   [image: delete account]
4. Click on the "Delete account" button.

   [image: button]
5. Click "Ok" to confirm.

   [image: confirm]

### Success!

[image: success]

Comment: They have now renamed the 'Delete Account' to 'Delete Team' which is much less disconcerting!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is old. Right now the next steps required:

1. Enter to your Team (you should see team's repositories).
2. Select 'Settings'.
3. You need to select under 'General' label a link 'Team settings'.
4. Click 'Delete account'